# weiterhin oder weiter

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> Die Leute werden ihr Leben weiterhin wie gewöhnlich führen können.

und

> Die Leute werden ihr Leben wie gewöhnlich weiter führen können.

Gibt es einen sinnlichen Unterschied?

Comment: Du könntest mal „sinnlich“ im Wörterbuch nachschlagen ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, es gibt hier durchaus einen Unterschied.

> Die Leute werden ihr Leben weiterhin wie gewöhnlich führen können.

bedeutet, dass die Leute ihre Gewohnheiten und Routinen auch in Zukunft beibehalten können und nicht ändern müssen.

> Die Leute werden ihr Leben wie gewöhnlich weiter führen können.

Bei genauer Betrachtung besagt dieser Satz hingegen, dass die Leute ihr Leben „*weiter* führen können“ im Gegensatz dazu, dass sie aufhören müssen, dieses zu führen. Es ist nicht ganz klar, was es bedeutet „sein Leben nicht führen zu können“. Dies klingt aber auf jeden Fall nach großem Unglück, Chaos oder Katastrophe. Es geht also weiter über das Ändern der Routinen hinaus.

Die unterschiedliche Wirkung entsteht durch die veränderte Position der Wörter „weiter“ bzw. „weiterhin“. Im zweiten Satz ist dieses betont. Man kann in beiden Sätzen „weiter“ und „weiterhin“ austauschen, ohne dass sich die Bedeutung stark verändert.

Ein Übersetzungsversuch der Sätze auf Englisch:

> People will be able to continue leading their lives as usual.

> People will be able to live on as usual.

Comment: der Unterschied liegt aber nicht so sehr im Unterschied weiter / weiterhin sondern an der Wortstellung wo sich das im Satz befindet.

Comment: @planetmaker Habe versucht das in meine Antwort aufzunehmen.

Comment: excellent answer thanks a lot